# Image_Encryption in node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

*I am trying to encrypt and decrypt the image and other files also by the code below. The code below can encrypt and decrypt files but not the image can someone help me encrypt and decrypt images? I have tried it various ways including converting the image to another file format but it did not work
*

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const fs = require("fs");

// encryption algorithm
const algorithm = "aes-256-ctr";
// secret key for increption
let key = "SecretKey";
key = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(String(key)).digest("base64").substr(0, 32);
// gives the result on the hash (digest)

/**
 *  encrypt
 * @param {*} buffer
 * @returns all the buffer objects in an array into one buffer object.
 */
const encrypt = (buffer) => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  //   creating new cipher using the algorithm, key, iv
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  //   creating new encrypted buffer
  const result = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(buffer), cipher.final()]);
  return result;
};

/**
 * decrypt
 * @param {*} encrypted
 * @returns
 */
const decrypt = (encrypted) => {
  const iv = encrypted.slice(0, 16);
  encrypted = encrypted.slice(16);
  //  create decipher
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  //  decrypt it
  const result = Buffer.concat([iv, decipher.update(encrypted), decipher.final()]);
  return result;
};

// the code below is for encryption

// fs.readFile("./sun.jpg", (err, file) => {
//   if (err) return console.log(err.message);
//   console.log("current file data ====>", file);

//   //   encrypt the file data
//   const encryptedFile = encrypt(file);
//   //   flow the encrypted file data to the new file
//   fs.writeFile("./sun.jpg", encryptedFile, (err, file) => {
//     if (err) return console.log(err.message);
//     if (file) {
//       console.log("File encrypted sucessfully");
//     }
//   });
// });

fs.readFile("./sun.jpg", (err, file) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err.message);
   //  decrypt the file data
  if (file) {
    const decryptedFile = decrypt(file);
    fs.writeFile("./sun.jpg", decryptedFile, (err, file) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err.message);
      if (file) {
        console.log("File decrypted sucessfully");
      }
    });
    console.log(decryptedFile.toString());
  }
});
```

Comment: Encryption works on bytes and does not see any file types. What does happen when you're encrypting an image file.